# Promises with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to generate a list of users with _.times but I get an array of Promised objects. How do I output an array of plain objects?

```
const createUser = async () => ({

});

const users = [];

_.times(5, () => users.push(createUser()));

Promise.all(users);
```

Output

```
[ Promise { { username: 'Armando', password: '8cw0W7Jpm0LSSS9' } },
  Promise { { username: 'Lauren', password: '9oFCK4rqLj_DGol' } },
  Promise { { username: 'Frederique', password: 'JXGOsjCCOMFBYFd' } },
  Promise { { username: 'Otilia', password: 'DnxArNIsjaVoMB2' } },
  Promise { { username: 'Elisabeth', password: 'kZbSlg7bVWiagFT' } } ]
```

Expected

```
[
  { username: 'Armando', password: '8cw0W7Jpm0LSSS9' },
  { username: 'Lauren', password: '9oFCK4rqLj_DGol' },
  { username: 'Frederique', password: 'JXGOsjCCOMFBYFd' },
  { username: 'Otilia', password: 'DnxArNIsjaVoMB2' },
  { username: 'Elisabeth', password: 'kZbSlg7bVWiagFT' }
]
```

Comment: `createUser` is async, so use any of the mechanisms to wait for an array of promises?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `await` the result of `Promise.all`:

```
const users = await Promise.all(userPromises)
```

**EDIT**

Using `await` will of course only work inside an `async` function -- thx for pointing that out in the comments Olian02.

Comment: Should add that `await` only works inside of `async` functions.

Answer (score 7):

You can get it in the `then` callback of `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(users).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```